# saving a dynamically created page by Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("p").after(" Hi .");
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

after i clicked the "Click me button" 5-6 times.. NEW HTML that is generated . isnt it ?

So I want to save that new generated HTML in a file through ASP.Net or PHP

Any idea's How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the body contents into a textarea and submit it in a form.

```
var css = $("style:first").html();  //this will ver the first style tag
$("#myCssTextarea")
         .val("<style type='text/css'>"+css+"</style>");

var html = $("body").html();
$("#myTextarea")
         .val(html)
         .parents("form")
         .submit();
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <textarea id="myTextarea" name="content" style="width:0; height:0;"></textarea>
     <textarea id="myCssTextarea" name="cssContent" style="width:0; height:0;"></textarea>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if($_POST["content"]){
     $file = fopen('mypage.html', 'w');
     fwrite($file, $_POST["content"]);
     fwrite($file, $_POST["cssContent"]);
     fclose($file);
}
```

**UPDATE** Added css storing code.

Comment: I would also like to send the CSS along the file, How can i do that ?

Comment: Is the CSS inline (in the html tags) or in a <style> tag?

Comment: Updated my answer for that last request.

Comment: i am getting an error " Notice: Undefined index: cssContent "

Comment: Did you create the new textarea with name="cssContent" ?

Comment: Oops Sorry i forgot to close the tag.... Well but still the Css is not showing  up... Its Not styling the text.

Comment: Got it, the jQuery selector a wrong capital letter please change it to `$("#myCssTextarea")` **instead of** `$("#MyCssTextarea")`

Comment: Try changing the selector as i suggested above and let me know

Comment: When i opened the File I could not see the Tag <style> </<style>  but instead the content of the tag were there. I think ill have to add the Style tag to make it work...  Isnt it ?

Comment: Ya i fixed that capital letter thing but still the style isnt loading

Comment: The tag itself was not there because it was only saving the contents, with this it should: `.val("<style type='text/css'>"+css+"</style>");` i also updated it in the answer.

Comment: Yes Sir, It worked Perfectly :)   
I have 1 more question Can i ask you that too ?

Comment: I want to "cache" the pages along with the CSS. The file_get_contents functions gets the content of a webpage but doesnt get the CSS which is in the webpage. Any ideas how can i get the CSS along with the file ?

Comment: That could get very complicated depending on the websites you want to fetch, sometimes the css paths are absolute (which is ok) and sometimes relative. I think you should post a new question for this particular issue. Also please consider setting this as the right answer to you initial question.

Comment: i asked but no one is replying on that , So i thought to ask you THE EXPERT :)

Comment: How can i save an Iframe ? i tried the same method but it did not work :(